# How to assign GET parameter to Value attribute of HTML Input Text?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have following HTML form in which I am getting name from get parameter. I am unable to assign the value of get parameter to the value attribute of form. In the text field "$_GET['name']" gets printed instead of its value. What I am doing wrong here in this code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="demo_form.asp">
  Name: <input type="text" name="name" value=$_GET['name']><br>
  Sex : <input type="text" name="sex" value="M"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit form">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: does your form really gets submitted to asp page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code should be this:

```
Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $_GET['name'];?>"/>
                                                 ^^^ you need to echo it
```

Answer (score 2):

thats because u have not specified php tags and the browser wont be able to fetch your result.
if you are using asp than please use asp tags instead of php tags.

```
<form action="demo_form.asp">
Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $_GET['name'] ?>"><br>
Sex : <input type="text" name="sex" value="M"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit form">
</form>
```